# Stack Exchange has a new, clearer, stricter privacy policy

Tags: discussion, legal, privacy

### [It's *here*.](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)

**Key changes include that it's now:**

- Actually readable by human non-lawyers
- Clearer and more specific about how we handle your private information
- Compliant with the stricter EU and Swiss privacy disclosure requirements
- More accessible, with a link in the footer of every page
- <strike>Now starring actual, active-duty navy seals.</strike>

(Some of you may have noticed that we posted the new policy a little while back; we waited to post this because it had not yet been certified to be Safe Harbor compliant by the DOC, which it now has.)

Comment: The sidebar summary's font renders really bad on Chrome, Win 7: http://i.stack.imgur.com/07kPF.png

Comment: @BenBrocka Do you have clear type enabled?

Comment: @BryanDunsmore Win 7 has Cleartype enabled by default

Comment: @BenBrocka Always troubleshoot the simplest problems first. =P

Comment: **"Legally Useless Summary for Short Attention Spans. (Yes, you still have to read the real one on the right. Sorry, but you do.)"** Pfft.

Comment: **"Your web browser tells us stuff like your approximate location and how you use the site. It also bakes us yummy cookies."** No... I think it stole the ones in my cookie jar. The ones that *I* baked.

Comment: **"If you don’t like cookies or have other dietary restrictions, please tell your browser."** What, so it can take them and have them all for itself? (Serious note: perhaps it should say "please tell your browser so it won't collect any from our site"? Just a suggestion.)

Comment: **but we’re not the boss of you and can’t make you.*** can't make you ***do what***?

Comment: @nhahtdh: "give us your email and other personal info" from the previous clause.

Comment: **"Working here rocks. We have insanely great health insurance, reimburse employees’ gym membership, and give employees free t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶p̶o̶r̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶u̶n̶i̶c̶o̶r̶n transit cards."** Alright, I'll shut up now. I don't want to give them any ideas.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: It is missing a word to refer to the previous clause.

Comment: Lesson: Never put a legal document, or abstract thereof, in front of a bunch of developers.

Comment: Is the spare comma in `(e.g., by publishing a report on trends in the usage of the network,)` intentional or does it help comply with Safe Harbor provisions?

Comment: @BenBrocka Same issue here (Win7 Firefox).

Comment: @sixlettervariables Adding. Punctuation. Increases. Clarity. [This. Is. Sparta!!!]

Comment: No way am I reading the long version...

Comment: @Benjol it's actually quite good copywriting for a privacy policy. It's long but readable

Comment: @Ben, oh yeah, it's readable, but not exactly, eh, *gripping*...

Comment: But I was looking for Keytar lessons

Comment: This is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The _new_, _clearer_, _stricter_ privacy policy doesn't answer a basic question -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s  Moreover, it appears that nobody from SE staff is interested in answering it either.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this is somewhat inane but, completely unrelated to the actual content of the policy, you guys need to define a better font stack for the left hand side condensed version of the policy. The current font stack

```
"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",'Arial Narrow Bold'
```

doesn't have a generic fallback font (`sans-serif`) associated, and more importantly, doesn't appear to work even with a clean Windows 7 installation. I'm not entirely sure how the font is distributed, but you probably won't find it on Linux or mobile operating systems either. The best way to fix this is to use a `@font-face` font instead, since operating systems aren't guaranteed to have a condensed font available.

I know, it's not a very important bug, but it does make the reading experience somewhat less enjoyable. Since the team took so much effort to write the condensed version I'd hope they put a little effort in making it look correct everywhere too.

Comment: is there a linux alternative of a condensed sans serif font I can use?

Comment: @jin Not one I can think of, no. I'm not sure if mobile browsers have them too. Does the iPad come with Helvetica Neue  Condensed?

Comment: @TimYiJiang, It appears to. I'm not sure how to confirm the font, but it certainly *looks* identical.